# CSS hover navigation / marble menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I have a vertical navigation bar that has buttons to where when hovered over, I would like for options to appear beside that button horizontally.

I have the HTML, I'm just not sure how to make the hover effects happen with CSS. What's the best method to achieve this?

HTML

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=7"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="about ZOPA" /></a></li>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Realty</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WM + SB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vendors</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end subs -->
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=16"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="ZOPA blog" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=13"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/share.png" alt="share with ZOPA" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=9"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="contact ZOPA" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.thezopateam.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/properties.png" alt="ZOPA properties" /></a></li>
                <ul class="subs">
                    <li><a href="#">Buying</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Selling</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end subs -->
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=11"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/gallery.png" alt="ZOPA gallery" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

updated css

```
nav li {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    position: relative; 
}

nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
}

nav li ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}

nav li:not(:hover) ul { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: In that markup, which elements are the buttons to be hovered, and which elements are the options which appear? Are you talking about submenus?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are going for, but hover css is simple. Example - ​a:hover { /* CSS Here*/ }​

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The first set of `<li>`s are the main buttons, `.sub` is what I would like to appear upon hover.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple demo of a submenu: http://jsbin.com/iyijed/1/edit

The key rule is `nav li:not(:hover) ul { display: none; }` - that's what hides your submenus until their parent is hovered.

If you have (old browser) issues with `:not`, you can simply put `display: none` on the submenus, and override it with `nav li:hover ul { display: block; }`.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. I've made the changes according to what I saw in the demo, but still the hover effect doesn't work. Could you take a look at the site? http://zoparealty.com/share/

Comment: Nevermind, I found my problem- left the `</li>`s on the items I wanted the hover menus.

Comment: OK, your markup is a little different in that the submenus are not children of their corresponding menu items. You can still *kind of* get [what you want](http://jsbin.com/iyijed/2/edit), but the submenus cannot be positioned relative to their "parents" since their parents are not actually their parents. Also semantically, it doesn't really make sense. So I would recommend changing your markup to make the submenu `ul`s children of the `li` menu items.

Comment: How can I have the `ul`s roll out horizontally like a continuous list?
Like hover me > leaf, leaf, leaf

Comment: You can use `nav li ul li { display: inline; }`, and you must put a width on `nav li ul` which is big enough to accommodate the whole horizontal list. Also, if you're still positioning the submenu with a value on `right`, you'll want to switch that to `left`.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support. I've updated my original question to show my CSS. The hover items are still displaying in a vertical list, not horizontal. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you close:

```
nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > ul.subs { 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right: 5%;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul.subs {
    display:block;
}
```