# How to make CSS hover effect persist after clicking Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="stayBlue">
        <img src="#"/>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="#" height="32px" width="32px"/>Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="#" height="32px" width="32px"/>Dropdown link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="#" height="32px" width="32px"/>Dropdown link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="#" height="32px" width="32px"/>Dropdown link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/ZuMv5/5/

I'd like the blue hover on the big button to remain when clicked/active, tried :active, :focus via CSS and some jQuery workarounds but nothing works. I'd prefer a solution via CSS if possible.

Also, is there any way to center the dropdown menu in relation to the big button above?

Comment: I checked several topics already, while some provide helpful tips I wasnt able to achieve it the way I show on the picture. Some were: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923435/css-hover-navigation-marble-menu   or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777166/styling-option-element-hover they are more like dropdown lists, but Im working on them as we speak, I appreciate your patience and if you feel you are doing the work for me, feel free to ignore it. Thank you.

Comment: This will help you to understand how SO works: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Skelly thanks for link, I've edited the post, hope it looks a bit more specific and simplified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following CSS:

```
.btn-group.open .btn.dropdown-toggle {
/*hover effect*/ }
```

Check it applied here: http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/ZuMv5/5/

Hope it helps others, thanks everyone.